# http.POST is not sending data to local web page

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, web

I am using a nodeMCU to send data to my local web page developed using Spring boot but when I run the code I don't get an error the esp8266 connects to WiFi but I don't get anything on my spring boot app or any responses. 
Here is the rest controller used from spring boot

```cpp
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/getallcadres")
public class cadreController {
    @Autowired
    cadreRepository cadre;

@PostMapping("/getnbpassage")
    public String getnbrpassage(@RequestBody String nb){
        System.out.println("nombre de passage = "+nb);
        return "received";

    }
}
```

and the Arduino code

```cpp
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);//Serial connection
  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.begin("Iphone de elaa", "27343550");   //WiFi connection

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {  //Wait for the WiFI connection completion

    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Waiting for connection");

  }
  Serial.println("Wifi is connected");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

}

void loop() {

 if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){   //Check WiFi connection status
 Serial.println("here we start");
   HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient

   http.begin("http://localhost:8080/getallcadres/getnbpassage");      //Specify request destination
   http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");  //Specify content-type header

   int httpCode = http.POST("5");   //Send the request
   String payload = http.getString();//Get the response payload

   Serial.println("return code"+httpCode);   //Print HTTP return code
   Serial.println(payload);    //Print request response payload

   http.end();  //Close connection

 }else{

    Serial.println("Error in WiFi connection");   

 }

  delay(30000);  //Send a request every 30 seconds

}
```

I am using Arduino IDE 1.6.5 here is what I get
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL has `localhost` as the host name. That cannot work. localhost means “self”, the computer initiating the request. In this case it would mean the ESP8266, if it even understood it. You need to use the name or the IP address of the computer running your spring boot app, not localhost.

Comment: thank you that worked for me